# "are internationally extrajudicial" or

Tags: grammaticality, word-order

As you know, an adverbis a word that modifies (describes) a verb (he sings loudly), an adjective (very tall), another adverb (ended too quickly), or even a whole sentence.
So, I was wondering which option below grammatically sounds more natural:

> **a.** There are many issues that **[internationally are extrajudicial](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22internationally+are+extrajudicial%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIR970IR970&hl=en-US&sxsrf=AOaemvLExAH9DET7v4SpvmFYqDau5J_HJA%3A1631008365915&ei=bTY3YfuhN6jBlwTlmZCoDQ&oq=%22internationally+are+extrajudicial%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBwgjEK4CECcyBQghEKABOgcILhBDEJMCOgUIABCABDoFCC4QgAQ6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgQIIxAnOgQILhBDOgUIABCRAlCtI1jiNmC3OGgDcAB4AIABigKIAYoCkgEDMi0xmAEAoAEBoAECwAEB&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)**. 
> **b.** There are many issues that **[are internationally extrajudicial](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+internationally+extrajudicial%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIR970IR970&hl=en-US&sxsrf=AOaemvIa11hsVycuCEnea8Yzr8agokSXxA%3A1631008416734&ei=oDY3YbG2LJO7lwTDi5DQCg&oq=%22are+internationally+extrajudicial%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBwgjEK4CECcyBQghEKABOgcIIxDqAhAnOgcILhDqAhAnOgQIIxAnOgUIABCRAjoECAAQQzoFCAAQgARQ_RdY-88BYObRAWgIcAB4AIABzQOIAZQJkgEFMy0yLjGYAQCgAQGgAQKwAQ_AAQE&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)**. 
> **c.** There are many issues that **[are extrajudicial internationally](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22are+extrajudicial+internationally%22&rlz=1CDGOYI_enIR970IR970&hl=en-US&sxsrf=AOaemvJzmyG5felsnjFbyp-2Ydb7gxarqA%3A1631008444760&ei=vDY3YZ7bLaPDlwS9uKGABQ&oq=%22are+extrajudicial+internationally%22&gs_lcp=ChNtb2JpbGUtZ3dzLXdpei1zZXJwEAMyBwgjEK4CECc6BwgjEOoCECc6BwguEOoCECc6BAgjECdQ1LoCWLbTAmCO1QJoAnAAeACAAe4CiAHCBZIBAzMtMpgBAKABAaABArABD8ABAQ&sclient=mobile-gws-wiz-serp)**.

Some of these issues include:

1. Harsh penalties for crimes.
2. Execution of offenders under legal age.
3. Restrictions on freedom of speech and the press.

When I search through the google, "a" and "c" hits zero results and "b" hits just one result. That was why I decided to ask about it here. Maybe that's just not a proper combination of words.
I was wondering which choice has a more natural word order.
Please let me know about it.

Comment: Rather than just requesting proofreading, add what grammar issues you are looking to resolve. "sounds more natural" isn't helpful, as it's different things to different people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most basic usage for adverbs is "adverbs modify verbs" (as you wrote). This one would be:

> b. There are many issues that **are internationally** extrajudicial.

The others are playing with word order.

But you should avoid "grammatically sounds more natural". What the grammar says is correct, and what "sounds natural" are often not the same thing, and how something sounds allows for more variability.